# Is this considered dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
int a;
cin >> a;
int n[a];
```

When I used Visual Studio the program did not compile and reported an error. But when I used terminal to compile the program ran without any issues. Why is it so? And is this considered dynamic memory allocation ?

Comment: It's g++ extension... It's a syntax that came from C99.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. This is not legal in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) or [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14). You are using an extension, called [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (that some, but not all, compilers provide).

<sup>Also, VLA don't work well for huge arrays - e.g. of several million components -, because in practice your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is limited (e.g. to a megabyte or a few of them)</sup>

[Dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#DYNAMIC) is internally using something like `new` (or `malloc`). It changes the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your process (thru [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on Linux, which would be sometimes called by `new`; on Windows something different is used.).

A good (and standard conforming) way to use dynamic memory would be to use some [standard container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Its data would be heap allocated (and released by the vector's [destructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_programming%29)).

Comment: Also, any arrays allocated with a fixed size, but not with `new` are gone after the destruction of the object while allocating it with `new` requires freeing that allocated space via the destructor to be efficient. The reason I say "fixed" is that even if you use `new`, the size has to come from somewhere, so that is technically a fixed size, even if it's not fixed for every single runtime